# html5 record computer sound

Tags: html, audio, record

I want to make a webpge that steams my music and ither sound of my computer to a other computer.
This computer is connected to my sound system

So is it possible to record the computer sound with html5?
I don' t mean the mic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not really the sort of thing you would (or could easily) do on a web page. Capturing all sound from a computer would need you to have an audio driver installed on that computer that was able to capture the audio output mix, or route it to an audio input.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do it in flash either, for the same reasons.